# if else using the next unique value in column by key

Tags: r, data.table

I have a question. How do I perform the following operations on the sampdata object? The result that I would like to have is the sampres object.

Thank you.

Pseudocode:

```
if sampdata[,flow[1] == flow[2], by = site_no]

sampdata[,flow[2]] = next unique flow value & take the corresponding gage value # if yes

no change   # if no
```

Starting data:

```
library(data.table)

sampdata <-     data.table(c(02446500,02446500,02446500,02467000,02467000,02467000,06818000,06818000,06818000,06818000,06893000,06893000,06893000,06893000,06934500,06934500,06934500,07010000,07010000,07010000,07289000,07289000,07289000),c(21,21,22,70,76,82,14700,14700,14700,14800,11000,11000,11000,11100,19400,19400,19500,32000,32000,32100,146000,146000,147000),c(4,4.01,4.02,73.05,73.06,73.07,1,1.01,1.02,1.03,1,1.01,1.02,1.03,-1.2,-1.19,-1.18,-9.02,-9.01,-9,-4.43,-4.42,-4.41))
setnames(sampdata,c("site_no", "flow", "gage"))
setkey(sampdata, site_no)
```

End result:

```
sampres <- data.table(c(02446500,02446500,02446500,02467000,02467000,02467000,06818000,06818000,06818000,06818000,06893000,06893000,06893000,06893000,06934500,06934500,06934500,07010000,07010000,07010000,07289000,07289000,07289000),c(21,22,22,70,76,82,14700,14800,14700,14800,11000,11100,11000,11100,19400,19500,19500,32000,32100,32100,146000,147000,147000),c(4,4.02,4.02,73.05,73.06,73.07,1,1.03,1.02,1.03,1,1.03,1.02,1.03,-1.2,-1.18,-1.18,-9.02,-9,-9,-4.43,-4.41,-4.41))
setnames(sampres,c("site_no", "newflow", "newgage"))
setkey(sampres, site_no)
```

To clarify, here are the initial data and result side-by-side, from `cbind(sampdata,sampres)`:

```
    site_no   flow  gage site_no   flow  gage
 1: 2446500     21  4.00 2446500     21  4.00
 2: 2446500     21  4.01 2446500     22  4.02
 3: 2446500     22  4.02 2446500     22  4.02
 4: 2467000     70 73.05 2467000     70 73.05
 5: 2467000     76 73.06 2467000     76 73.06
 6: 2467000     82 73.07 2467000     82 73.07
 7: 6818000  14700  1.00 6818000  14700  1.00
 8: 6818000  14700  1.01 6818000  14800  1.03
 9: 6818000  14700  1.02 6818000  14700  1.02
10: 6818000  14800  1.03 6818000  14800  1.03
11: 6893000  11000  1.00 6893000  11000  1.00
12: 6893000  11000  1.01 6893000  11100  1.03
13: 6893000  11000  1.02 6893000  11000  1.02
14: 6893000  11100  1.03 6893000  11100  1.03
15: 6934500  19400 -1.20 6934500  19400 -1.20
16: 6934500  19400 -1.19 6934500  19500 -1.18
17: 6934500  19500 -1.18 6934500  19500 -1.18
18: 7010000  32000 -9.02 7010000  32000 -9.02
19: 7010000  32000 -9.01 7010000  32100 -9.00
20: 7010000  32100 -9.00 7010000  32100 -9.00
21: 7289000 146000 -4.43 7289000 146000 -4.43
22: 7289000 146000 -4.42 7289000 147000 -4.41
23: 7289000 147000 -4.41 7289000 147000 -4.41
    site_no   flow  gage site_no   flow  gage
```

Thank you for the edits. <s>I have added bold to the flow/gage combinations that are the same.</s> The next unique flow value and the corresponding gage value need to become the 2nd newflow/newgage values.

This is a small set of data that I'm trying to find an automated solution for because I made those changes by hand. I'm trying to determine an automated way of making the changes since I have several thousand sites that I need to work with. Thank you.

Comment: Well, it's definitely an `rle` sort of problem.

Comment: One thing you don't say explicitly is how "gage" changes. I guess you take the value from the same place you got the "next unique flow value"?

Comment: @Frank Yes, I am taking the newgage value from the gage value where I obtained the next unique flow value. So far I have tried unique(flow), but I don't know of a way to get the corresponding gage values at those unique flow points.

Comment: Ok. FYI, the bold doesn't seem to be rendering inside the code block, maybe just put an asterisk at the end of each affected (or unaffected) row?

Answer (score 1):

This function was designed before I realized this was just within narrow site groups but it works nonetheless:

```
swapfun <- function(x){ samp <- rle(x); 
              unlist( sapply(
                         seq_along(samp$lengths), 
                             function(x) {
                                t <- rep(samp$values[x], samp$lengths[x])
                                if(samp$lengths[x] >1) {t[2] <- samp$values[x+1]}
                                t}
                             )
                     )
                          }

sampdata[ , newflow:=swapfun(flow), by=site_no]
> sampdata
    site_no   flow  gage newflow
 1: 2446500     21  4.00      21
 2: 2446500     21  4.01      22
 3: 2446500     22  4.02      22
 4: 2467000     70 73.05      70
 5: 2467000     76 73.06      76
 6: 2467000     82 73.07      82
 7: 6818000  14700  1.00   14700
 8: 6818000  14700  1.01   14800
 9: 6818000  14700  1.02   14700
10: 6818000  14800  1.03   14800
11: 6893000  11000  1.00   11000
12: 6893000  11000  1.01   11100
13: 6893000  11000  1.02   11000
14: 6893000  11100  1.03   11100
15: 6934500  19400 -1.20   19400
16: 6934500  19400 -1.19   19500
17: 6934500  19500 -1.18   19500
18: 7010000  32000 -9.02   32000
19: 7010000  32000 -9.01   32100
20: 7010000  32100 -9.00   32100
21: 7289000 146000 -4.43  146000
22: 7289000 146000 -4.42  147000
23: 7289000 147000 -4.41  147000
```

Comment: Thank you for the function. The newflow is what I need, but there isn't a way to also grab the corresponding gage at that flow value & not all of the unique flow values occur at +1.

Comment: What is this supposed to mean: `not all of the unique flow values occur at +1`?

Comment: And ... does the answer to the prior question mean that you need to make your example more complex to accurately represent that concern?